# C: Replacing Escape Characters esp '\\'

Tags: c, escaping, character

This portion of my code is supposed to replace all escape characters read (as they can muck stuff up) with their hex code in parentheses. It works except for the escape character for backslash '\\' and I can't figure out why.

```
if(bt[j] == '\\')
{
   switch(bt[j+1])
   case 'n':
      strcat(at,"(0x0a)");break;
   case ...
      ...
   case '\\':
      strcat(at,"(0x5c)");break;
   ...
...
}
```

edit:
I need to remove backslashes that aren't escape characters.
So "hello\nb\ob" would be "hello(0x0a)bob"
and "hello\nb\\ob" would be "hello(0x0a)b(0x5c)ob"

Comment: Perhaps a typo but you're missing a semicolon after case '\\'

Comment: Well I need to differentiate between a \\ read and a \ read.

Comment: @NicholasKunze If it's a single character it is '\', and it can't be '\\' except to indicate that (in code) that it's a single '\'.

Comment: NicholasKunze  Is the comment of @David Beech correct?? Code should be `case '\\':`  ':' added.

Comment: Been a while since I coded in c but I believe you need a ':' there. Like with case 'n' :

Comment: I thought that was just a typo posting it here though. Did that fix it? If so I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void func(char at[], char bt[]){
    int j;
    for(j=0; bt[j]; ++j){
        switch(bt[j]){
        case '\n':
            memcpy(at, "(0x0a)", 6);
            at += 6;
            break;
        case '\\':
            memcpy(at, "(0x5c)", 6);
            at += 6;
            break;
        //...
        default:
            *at++ = bt[j];
        }
    }
    *at = '\0';
}

int main(){
    char at[256];
    char *bt;
    func(at, "hello\nb\ob");
    puts(at);
    func(at, "hello\nb\\ob");
    puts(at);
    return 0;
}
```